# How to compare characters in two CharSequences

Tags: java, android, string-comparison

How should I compare two characters of two `CharSequence`s?

These are my two `CharSequence`s:

```
CharSequence name1 = fname.getText();
CharSequence name2 = sname.getText();
```

If I try to compare like this:

```
if(name1[i] == name2[j])
```

..it gives me errors.

Comment: Simply use the Character class like this: `Character.compare(name1.charAt(i),name2.charAt(i))`. if the result is < 0  then char of name1 <  char at name2. if result > 0 then it is the reverse. if the result == 0, then the 2 chars have the same value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String name1 = editText1.getText().toString();
String name2 = editText2.getText().toString();
```

To compare particular `char`s in your String, you can use `char charAt(int)` method also from `String` type. Here is example use:

```
if(name1.charAt(2) == name2.charAt(0)){
   // Do your stuff
}
```

You have to remember that `char charAt(int)` is zero-based so 0 is first, 1 is second and so on.
And in this example you can see that I compared two chars just like I would compare `int`egers - with simple `==`.

Comparing whole `String`s:

```
// This returns true if Strings are equal:
name1.contentEquals(name2);    

// This returns 0 if Strings are equal:
name1.compareTo(name2);
```

To make it case insensitive you can use method from `String` type `toLowerCase()` on both `String`s.

```
name1.equalsIgnoreCase(name2);
```

or:

```
name1.toLowerCase().contentEquals(name2.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: charAt() is defined in CharSequence, and it would be less efficient to convert them to Strings first -- perhaps not even possible (there is no constraint on CharSequence to suggest that all the characters in it need to be able to fit in memory).

Comment: I second @Jules response. If you are going to compare CharSequences you should implement something along the lines of java.util.Arrays.equals(char[], char[]) and keep them as CharSequences and use charAt where you see array access. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.equals%28char%5B%5D%2Cchar%5B%5D%29

Answer (score 7):

Use [CharSequence.html#charAt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#charAt%28int%29) to get the `char`  at a specified position.
You can then compare `char` with `==`

Regarding your code in the question, this will result in

```
if(name1.charAt(i) == name2.charAt(j))
```

Answer (score 5):

If possible compare two `Strings`,

Instead of `ChracterSequence` comparison something like,

```
String name1 = edtTextName1.getText().toString().trim();
String name2 = edtTextName2.getText().toString().trim();

if(name1.equals(name2))
{
Log.i("Result","True");
}
else
{ 
Log.i("Result","false");
}
```

Comment: A CharSequence is a readable sequence of characters. This interface provides uniform, read-only access to many different kinds of character sequences. So if you have to compare these two you have to go through each character of those sequence using loop, so its better to change it in string then compare it.

Comment: i mean i m using a char sequence and i can't pass this charsequence to a string.
Also i'm comparing the characters of Sequence not the whole string.

How do i do it with CharSequence??
(I am very new to android, sry)

Comment: You don't need to use charsequence just use direct string as per example in answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
String name1 = fname.getText().toString();
String name2 = sname.getText().toString();
if(name1.equals(name2)){/* do something */}
```

Comment: I am not using strings nor you can pass the CharSequence to a string. How do i campare CharSequence. And also i m comparing the characters not whole Sequence.

Comment: CharSequence is an interface, not a concrete class.  You can't actually create an instance of a CharSequence.  See documentation here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html you need a String (which you can access like an array if you don't want to use the built-in equals method, or a StringBuffer, because those are actual concrete implementations of CharSequence

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, since Java 11, there is a new method [CharSequence.compare()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html#compare(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)). If you want to check two char sequences for equality, you can use:

```
CharSequence.compare(name1, name2) == 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
name1.toString().contentEquals(name2);
```